# Using .net 8 and simple api controller is not accessible from anywhere and says 404 not found. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-8.0

I am using .net 8 and created very simple project with this controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class InterestsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<InterestsController> _logger;

        public InterestsController(ILogger<InterestsController> logger) 
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

    [HttpGet("GetInterests")]
    public ActionResult GetInterests() 
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("GetInterests method called: ");
        return Ok("interests");
    }

    }
}
```

Now when i try to access this from browser or postman like http://localhost:5264/api/interests/GetInterests; it says '404 not found'.

Why? Its very clear here and it should work.

Further settings.

program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

 app.Run();
```

launchSettings.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:11726",
      "sslPort": 44386
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5264",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7201",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:7204;",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to verify with different ports, tried browser, tried postman with GET verb and even swagger is not picking it. Why? Is this some .net 8 issue?

Comment: Can you post  your swagger and check the endpoint is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving a '404 Not Found' because you have not added the necessary services for the controllers to work.

In your Program.cs file, you need to ensure you are adding your controller(s).

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
```

You will also need to map them.

```
app.MapControllers();
```

Example Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

More information can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#ar6

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to verify with different ports, tried browser, tried postman
> with GET verb and even swagger is not picking it. Why? Is this some
> .net 8 issue?

Well, first of all this is not merely .NET 8 issue or anything. This can be applied regardless of any version.

Based on my test and investigation, I have taken a absolutely fresh .NET 8 web api project and I just replaced your code snippet and seems working without any modification.

What I have found the difference is your program.cs which really doesn't matched or your are missing the necessary middleware registration that also has mentioned by other contributor.

Based on your shared code snippet, you should encounter middleware exception as following before getting 404:

[image]

So without controller middleware service, we cannot reach to your endpoint.  please update following snippet and try.

My Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**Note:** The controller code would remain unchanged. Your shared controller snippet seems correct.

Swagger and Postman Output:

[image]

**Note:** Please [check the basic middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#register-the-database-context) we need in order to [run Web API project.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#register-the-database-context)